# How do I identify physical size of Procedural textures?

Tags: texturing, procedural

is there a way I can find out how much space a Procedural texture takes up on disk when it is applied/not applied to an object?

Thank you,

Comment: Are you sure that a procedural texture takes any space on disk ?
The texture is computed on cpu and sent to GPU, space taken here will depend on the screen resolution since it's vectorial (that's just my guess)

Comment: To quote Wikipedia here: _"In computer graphics, a procedural texture is a texture created using a mathematical description (i.e. an algorithm) rather than directly stored data."_ So as @Yvain already stated, it hardly takes any space on disk. Of course while rendering the data of the generated texture has to be stored somewhere temporarily and complex textures (might) cost a lot of memory, but if you mean disk space when saving the file it's negligible, it is like e.g. the RGB node, it only stores the information about the node and its settings, but not the complex generated texture.

Answer (score 1):

Sure - render the thing with the texture and then render the thing without the texture and then compare the memory used during rendering.

[image: A fairly complex procedural wood texture]

When I do this with a fairly complex procedural wood texture my render uses 5.19MB in memory and without the texture it's 5.17MB so the amount of memory used is really negligible. Render times on the other hand, may go up quite a bit if you have a lot of complex procedural textures.

Same way one can save the file with the texture and without it to compare the file size:
[image]

I get a difference of 131KB and that looks believable  for something like this
[image]

Comment: The question is "how much space a Procedural texture takes up on disk". The way it is phrased doesn't seem like asking for the (temporary) memory usage during rendering.

Comment: Oh, then one can save the file with it and then without it same way. The amount will still be very small.

Comment: Very nice wood! I'd nick that if I could see it :D

Comment: Yeah, the wood material is nice... but unfortunately a secret I guess ;) Anyway, I think the most storage consumption of a procedural texture in the file is the amount of nodes and their settings which most of the time isn't too much. At least not compared to high quality image texures.